# How to specific installed include/lib path when using cmake find_package module mode?

Tags: c++, cmake, build, compilation

> Please be noticed that this question is not about to specific the search paths of FindOpenMP.cmake in module mode or the locations of OpenMPConfig.cmake in config mode, but to specific the exactly openmp installed path when we've already using the module mode.

I've built a libomp from source by the [LLVM-project](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/tree/release/12.x). And i still want to use the gcc shipped default omp in some of my program while using this build-from-source libomp in other specificed program. So i install the build-from-source omp in path like `/root/openmp-with-tsan`. In the project's CMakeLists.txt, switch the libomp implementation like:

```
if (USE_OPENMP_WITH_TSAN)
    add_definitions("-DUSE_OPENMP")
    find_package(OpenMP PATHS "/root/openmp-with-tsan" REQUIRED)
endif ()
```

Of course, it didn't work, i've learned from the [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html) documentation page that the usage of `PATHS` means that i am using full signature, so config mode is applied. Since the installed build-from-source openmp didn't provide a OpenMPConfig.cmake in the corresponding path, the search fail.

```
  find_package considered the following locations for the Config module:

    /usr/local/OpenMPConfig.cmake
    /usr/local/openmp-config.cmake
    /usr/OpenMPConfig.cmake
    /usr/openmp-config.cmake
    /OpenMPConfig.cmake
    /openmp-config.cmake
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cmake/data/OpenMPConfig.cmake
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cmake/data/openmp-config.cmake
    /opt/OpenMPConfig.cmake
    /opt/openmp-config.cmake
    /root/openmp-with-tsan/OpenMPConfig.cmake
    /root/openmp-with-tsan/openmp-config.cmake

  The file was not found.
```

Cmake did provide a [FindOpenMP.cmake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindOpenMP.html) for module mode search. However, it seems that in my machine, it will only look for these paths:

```
CMake Debug Log at /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindOpenMP.cmake:259 (find_library):
  find_library called with the following settings:

    VAR: OpenMP_omp_LIBRARY
    NAMES: "omp"
    Documentation: Path to the omp library for OpenMP
    Framework
      Only Search Frameworks: 0
      Search Frameworks Last: 0
      Search Frameworks First: 0
    AppBundle
      Only Search AppBundle: 0
      Search AppBundle Last: 0
      Search AppBundle First: 0
    NO_DEFAULT_PATH Enabled

  find_library considered the following locations:

    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/(lib)omp(\.so|\.a)
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/(lib)omp(\.so|\.a)
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/(lib)omp(\.so|\.a)
    /lib64/(lib)omp(\.so|\.a)
    /usr/lib/(lib)omp(\.so|\.a)
    /usr/lib/llvm-12/lib/(lib)omp(\.so|\.a)
    /lib/(lib)omp(\.so|\.a)

  The item was not found.
```

Obviously, the `/root/openmp-with-tsan` is not included.

So my question is, is there anyway to specific the exactly include/lib installation path for find_package module mode search?

---

The toolchain file that i used:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR x86_64)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /usr/bin/clang-12)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/bin/clang++-12)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_INIT "-fsanitize=thread -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_INIT "-fsanitize=thread")
```

Comment: Try setting `OpenMP_ROOT` to `/root/openmp-with-tsan` before calling `find_package`.

Comment: @ixSci Thanks for you reply, but it did not work on my project. I've tried to explicitly set ```CMP0074``` in my CMakesList.txt, not work either. Is it because i am using a toolchain file to set the compiler to chain from default host gcc to clang?

Comment: Usually that should not matter but the openmp module seems [pretty involved](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindOpenMP.cmake) so I can't say for sure. You can study it and debug against your system (you can even copy it and set `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` to where it is located to help you with the debugging) to find out what is wrong.

Comment: It seems that `FindOpenMP.cmake` module doesn't expect one to use `omp` library which is not shipped with the compiler. This could explain why it passes `NO_DEFAULT_PATH` option to the `find_library` call: this option disables external hits about locations to search. However, you could always set `OpenMP_omp_LIBRARY` **cache** variable manually (in the command line or in the toolchain). This setting is not guarantee to work with other CMake versions, but it seems not of your concern.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Or maybe can i use the found imported target by FindOpenMP.cmake and manually set the target properties to point to the ```openmp-with-tsan``` position before execute ```target_link_libraries(mytarget OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX)```?

Comment: I have the same problem, but for (an older version) of SQLite3.  FindSQLite3.cmake exists, and I set ${SQLite3_ROOT}, but no joy. Why doesn't "module mode" support HINTS/PATHS?